# Linker error trying to build and run unit tests

Tags: ros, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting an error from the linker when I attempt to run catkin_make run_tests_my_package`

The error I get is:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmy_package
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Under testing in my CMakelist.txt I have the following:
catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/utest.cpp)
if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
endif()

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

Am I missing something? do I need to use add_executable in my CMakelist.txt?

Another thing to mention is my workspace layout, it's arranged as follows:
my_package/
bin/
build/
src/
my_class.h
my_class.cpp
test/
utest.cpp
world/
CMakelist.txt

and inside utext.cpp I am referencing my_class.h list this `#include "my_package/my_class.h`

Full [CMakelist.txt](https://gist.github.com/streetdragon/7d3d14d7cf0965f77efe)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190891/linker-error-trying-to-build-and-run-unit-tests/) by [Kurt](https://answers.ros.org/users/20061/kurt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The linker is complaining that `my_package` is not a library. Do you create a library named my_package in your CMakeLists.txt? (Including your FULL CMakeLists.txt would be useful here).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt](https://answers.ros.org/users/20061/kurt/) on 2014-08-21**:
Yeah, I'm not actually including a cpp, was just a typo. I don't think I am creating a library called my_package in my CMakelist.txt. Here is the full [CMakelist.txt](https://gist.github.com/streetdragon/7d3d14d7cf0965f77efe)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-21**:
Wow... there's some unusual bits in there. If you're trying to write a test which tests the ActorLibrary, you should probably be linking it against the ActorLibrary in the same way that you link your primary executable.

**Comment by [Kurt](https://answers.ros.org/users/20061/kurt/) on 2014-08-21**:
Cool that seems to have worked, I've managed to build and the the tests by modifying the target_link_libraries to this target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ActorLibrary ${catkin_LIBRARIES})